# Аutocomplete jQuery в событии close или select переменная ui.item undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

Столкнулся с проблеммой при использовании плагина Аutocomplete. Версия jQuery 3.4.1, версия jQuery Ui 1.12.
Формирую массив:

```js
hints_array = []
$.each(arr, function(id, name) {

  hints_array.push({
    label: name.name,
    value: name.name,
    test: id
  });
});
```

Получаю данные такого вида:

```js
....
0: {
  label: "Карта памяти micro sd 32 teamgroup cl10 adapter",
  value: "Карта памяти micro sd 32 teamgroup cl10 adapter",
  test: "207"
}
1: {
  label: "Флешка flash 8gb teamgroup c12g usb2.0",
  value: "Флешка flash 8gb teamgroup c12g usb2.0",
  test: "209"
}
2: {
  label: "Вентилятор usb fan mi orange",
  value: "Вентилятор usb fan mi orange",
  test: "314"
}
3: {
    label: "Флешка flash 32gb kingston se9 usb2.0",
    value: "Флешка flash 32gb kingston se9 usb2.0",
    test: "318"
  }
  ....
```

Сам плагин:

```js
$('#name').autocomplete({
    source: hints_array,
    minLength: 0,
    close: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item);
    },
    position: {
      my: "left bottom",
      at: "left top",
      collision: "flip"
    }
  })
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val()) //auto trigger the search with whatever in the box
  })
}
```

Где на событии close не могу получить значение выбранного элемента. 
Очень прошу помощи, голова пухнет.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт. Поменял событие close на select.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/398214)

Comment: @doox911 Почему не является? Это и есть автор.

Comment: @0xdb этот вопрос вообще следует удалить.

Comment: @doox911 Правильно, а ответ пока пусть останется.